# FAIL-NEW: Proxy Disclosure [40025] OWASP ZAP

Tags: apache, proxy, owasp, zap

I am trying to verify the different rules using OWASP ZAP where there is a failure in:

```
FAIL-NEW: Proxy Disclosure [40025] x 1
        https://test.my-site.com (200 OK)
```

The ZAP docs provide the solution for the alert [over here](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/alerts/40025/), which states that:

> Disable the 'TRACE' method on the proxy servers, as well as the origin web/application server. Disable the 'OPTIONS' method on the proxy servers, as well as the origin web/application server, if it is not required for other purposes, such as 'CORS' (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). Configure the web and application servers with custom error pages, to prevent 'fingerprintable' product-specific error pages being leaked to the user in the event of HTTP errors, such as 'TRACK' requests for non-existent pages. Configure all proxies, application servers, and web servers to prevent disclosure of the technology and version information in the 'Server' and 'X-Powered-By' HTTP response headers.

Working on the solutions, I have done the following operations:

1. Blocked TRACE, TRACK, and OPTIONS rules in **.htaccess** file as below:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   # Disable TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
   RewriteRule .* - [F]

   # Disable OPTIONS HTTP method
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^OPTIONS
   RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]
   ```
2. Removing the headers that include web server details i.e.

   - X-Powered-By => not seen in the header
   - Server => removed apache included in the header and only shows `Server`   , which can be seen in the image below.

     [![Apache server details hidden][2]][2]

**Following all the solutions even haven't resolved the above issue.**

If anything is not clear I can provide some more information.

**Edit:**

I am running a full scan in the terminal and I am getting these warnings and errors:

[image: failed-rules-terminal]

The result stored in the XML file appears as follows:

```
<alertitem>
    <pluginid>40025</pluginid>
    <alertRef>40025</alertRef>
    <alert>Proxy Disclosure</alert>
    <name>Proxy Disclosure</name>
    <riskcode>2</riskcode>
    <confidence>2</confidence>
    <riskdesc>Medium (Medium)</riskdesc>
    <confidencedesc>Medium</confidencedesc>
    <desc>&lt;p&gt;1 proxy server(s) were detected or fingerprinted. This information helps a potential attacker to determine &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; - A list of targets for an attack against the application.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; - Potential vulnerabilities on the proxy servers that service the application.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; - The presence or absence of any proxy-based components that might cause attacks against the application to be detected, prevented, or mitigated. &lt;/p&gt;</desc>
    <instances>
        
            <instance>
                <uri>https://test.my-site.com</uri>
                <method>GET</method>
                <param></param>
                <attack>TRACE, OPTIONS methods with &apos;Max-Forwards&apos; header. TRACK method.</attack>
                <evidence></evidence>
            </instance>
        
    </instances>
    <count>1</count>
    <solution>&lt;p&gt;Disable the &apos;TRACE&apos; method on the proxy servers, as well as the origin web/application server.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Disable the &apos;OPTIONS&apos; method on the proxy servers, as well as the origin web/application server, if it is not required for other purposes, such as &apos;CORS&apos; (Cross Origin Resource Sharing).&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Configure the web and application servers with custom error pages, to prevent &apos;fingerprintable&apos; product-specific error pages being leaked to the user in the event of HTTP errors, such as &apos;TRACK&apos; requests for non-existent pages.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Configure all proxies, application servers, and web servers to prevent disclosure of the technology and version information in the &apos;Server&apos; and &apos;X-Powered-By&apos; HTTP response headers.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</solution>
    <otherinfo>&lt;p&gt;Using the TRACE, OPTIONS, and TRACK methods, the following proxy servers have been identified between OWASP ZAP and the application/web server: &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;- Unknown&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;The following web/application server has been identified: &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;- Unknown&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</otherinfo>
    <reference>&lt;p&gt;https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.1.2&lt;/p&gt;</reference>
    <cweid>200</cweid>
    <wascid>45</wascid>
    <sourceid>231</sourceid>
</alertitem>
```

Comment: Provide the response details from the HTTP message ZAP associates with the alert.

Comment: @kingthorin I have added the result exported by zap and the output image shown when using zap in docker and performing a full scan. If there is anything that I need to add please let me know.

Comment: That doesn't help. You'd either need to interact with the API and get a proper report or alert details, or use ZAPs GUI. Whatever you've done to address the issue is not what ZAP is seeing obviously. The code for that specific rule is here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/main/addOns/ascanrulesBeta/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrulesBeta/ProxyDisclosureScanRule.java if you want to read it and understand what it is encountering.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)